# EmberJS: Observing JavaScript object's getter in computed properties

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a JavaScript object with dynamically computed properties (using getter and setters), returned by a third party library and I want to observe them on my Ember computed properties.

If I pass such a property as a dependency in my computed property like below,

```
someProperty: computed('jsObject.property', function () {
    // Do something
})
```

Ember makes it `undefined`. Is this is bug in Ember or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Where is it undefined?

Comment: The dependent key `jsObject` should be a class property. Is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember supports watching ES5 getters only from version 2.4 (https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/12491). Updating fixed my issue.